# Angular bindonce vs native javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very large amount of data to put into the DOM which is causing a rendering performance bottleneck.

I'm restricted to using a pre-1.3 version of angular so there is no native bind once feature, but I could potentially use a plug-in to get that in. My question is, would there be a big performance difference in terms of initial rendering time or otherwise, between a bindonce implementation vs wrapping native javascript and/or templating engine inside angular to generate the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial render time isn't really going to improve with one-time binding. **It will however [improve overall performance](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) once the DOM tree is rendered.**

If you really need super fast rendering of very large data sets, you might consider some of [the examples where people are using React](http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/242/Improving-AngularJS-long-list-rendering-performance-using-ReactJS/).

Comment: Could using React be faster than manually inserting the DOM natively?

Comment: React does a lot more than just templating and inserting into the DOM. It does some pretty super smart things to ensure any DOM updates are as efficient as possible. It might be overkill for your use case, but I tend to err on the side of *already done* rather than try to implement something myself.